# ruby gem to check the users who all are logged in our application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any way or gem to identify the users who all are logged in our application ? . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by defining the extra field say, `status` in your table say, `users`.

So when any user gets `logged in`, you have to set this field with status as say, online.

Then in your controller's create method you just do the following:

```
User.create(:status => "online", #other params go here)
```

Also you may define the new registered user with the status say, `offline`.

This you can do at the time of user registration by doing so:

```
User.new(:status => "offline", #other params go here)
```

Then to find the logged in users, you can do so:

```
@online_users = User.where(:status => "online")
```

UPDATE:

For the users who does not clicks logout button, the above idea will not work.

So you have to combine this idea with something like [Jugernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/) and then send periodic pings to know if the user is still there.

Comment: ya. superb idea.. i am waiting for some more answers, if others not suits i will accept your answer. giving +1

Comment: you don't know when user go offline, ussaly no one click logout btn.. need some field like last_activity time and check onlin e status by this field maybe

Comment: when to update this last_activity time?? can u explain?? else post one new answer..

Comment: For that you also have to use something like http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/ to know when the user is online by sending periodic pings.

Answer (score 2):

Well first you would need to use something else besides CookieStore as your sessions backend. If you use for example ActiveRecord, you should be able to query all of the currently logged in users with relative ease.

I don't know of a gem for this, but this really doesn't sound something like you'd need one for either.

Comment: what is CookieStore?? Can you explain in brief..

Comment: By default Rails stores your session info in cookies. Meaning only you know your session data, the server doesn't know anything unless the clients passes that info. This also means that the server has no knowledge of all the cookies that exist (i.e all the sessions that exist) and it's not possible to count them. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

Comment: ya. good idea.. i am waiting for some more answers, if others not suits i will accept your answer. giving +1

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on which gem you are using for login system.

If you are using Authlogic, I can't remember for sure all the fields that are created for user model, but I believe you can do with a search like defining in name scope and searching for **last_request_at** to be in less then 5-10 minutes.

If you are using Devise, and if you especially want to use a gem, you can try with this:
https://github.com/ctide/devise_lastseenable